# How to get top 1 from union tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I'm getting duplicate records. I was wondering how to just pull the top 1 with the highest "docdate- last date received" could anyone point me in the right direction. I am a novice to sql queries. I'm using MS sql sever 2016.

```
(
        select a.vendorid,
            max(a.DOCDATE) as [Last Date Received],
            max(b.VENDNAME) as [Vendor Name] --, b.VNDCLSID
            --  ,a.* 
        from PM20000 a
        inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
        where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
        group by a.VENDORID
        )

union

(
    select a.VENDORID,
        max(a.DOCDATE) as [Last Date Received],
        max(b.VENDNAME) as [Vendor Name] --, b.VNDCLSID
        --,a.* 
    from PM30200 a
    inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
    where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
    group by a.VENDORID
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single row with the latest `[Last Date Received]`:

```
select top 1 *
from (
    select a.vendorid,
        a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
        b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
    from PM20000 a
    inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
    where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
    union all
    select a.VENDORID,
        a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
        b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
    from PM30200 a
    inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
    where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
    ) u
order by [Last Date Received] desc
```

---

For the latest `[Last Date Received]` for each `VendorId` using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select top 1 with ties *
from (
        select a.vendorid,
            a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
            b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
        from PM20000 a
        inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
        where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
    union all
    select a.VENDORID,
        a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
        b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
    from PM30200 a
    inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
    where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
    ) u
order by row_number() over (partition by VendorId order by [Last Date Received] desc)
```

---

Using a common table expression and ordering by `[Last Date Received] desc`:

```
;with cte as (
  select top 1 with ties *
  from (
      select a.vendorid,
          a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
          b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
      from PM20000 a
      inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
      where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
      union all
      select a.VENDORID,
          a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
          b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
        from PM30200 a
      inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
      where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
    ) u
  order by row_number() over (partition by VendorId order by [Last Date Received] desc)
)
select 
    VendorId
  , VendorName
  , [Last Date Received]
  , Days_LastInvoiced = datediff(day,[Last Date Received],getdate())
from cte
order by [Last Date Received] desc
```

---

without the common table expression...

```
select 
    VendorId
  , VendorName
  , [Last Date Received]
  , Days_LastInvoiced = datediff(day,[Last Date Received],getdate())
from (
  select top 1 with ties *
  from (
      select a.vendorid,
          a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
          b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
      from PM20000 a
      inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
      where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
      union all
      select a.VENDORID,
          a.DOCDATE as [Last Date Received],
          b.VENDNAME as [Vendor Name] 
      from PM30200 a
      inner join PM00200 b on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
      where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
    ) u
  order by row_number() over (partition by VendorId order by [Last Date Received] desc)
)
order by [Last Date Received] desc
```

Comment: that works perfect!! thanks. I have a question though.... Why is there a u here -------------              ) u
order by row_number() over (partition by VendorId order by [Last Date Received] desc)

Comment: @Jenesis Because the `(select ... union all select ... )` is a derived table and needs an alias, in this case I used `u`. The `row_number() ...` returns a value based on the `partition` and `order by` clauses, and we are returning rows where that value is 1 by using the `with ties` modifier to `top 1`.

Comment: @Jenesis Updated

Comment: how would I order them desc from last invoiced date.? I tried using your query 'common table expression and ordering by [Last Date Received] desc------- but got an error message. then i added----- datediff(day,DOCDATE,getdate()) as Days_LastInvoiced ----- but it didnt work.. any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: @Jenesis Did the error say you needed a semicolon? Add a semicolon before `with`.

Comment: I'm not even totally sure if the datediff(day,DOCDATE,getdate()) as Days_LastInvoiced --- is what is need to complete the query. I'm just trying to take the results of ---- For the latest [Last Date Received] for each VendorId using top with ties with row_number() query ------ and put it in alphabetical order, desc. I'm having issues with different errors none stated the semicolon

Comment: @Jenesis I added a query without a cte at the end... try modifying the last `order by` to whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, I would suggest that you do the `TOP` *before* doing the `UNION` . . . and to use `UNION ALL`:

```
select top 1 *
from ((select top 1 a.vendorid, max(a.DOCDATE) as [Last Date Received],
              max(b.VENDNAME) as [Vendor Name]
       from PM20000 a inner join
            PM00200 b
            on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
      where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
      group by a.VENDORID
      order by [Last Date Received] desc
     )
     union all
     (select top 1 a.VENDORID, max(a.DOCDATE) as [Last Date Received],
             max(b.VENDNAME) as [Vendor Name] 
      from PM30200 a inner join
           PM00200 b
           on a.VENDORID = b.VENDORID
      where b.VNDCLSID in ('cb', '6')
      group by a.VENDORID
      order by [Last Date Received] desc
    )
   ) tt
order by [Last Date Received] desc;
```

As SQLZim points out, use `with ties` if you duplicates.

Comment: thanks for your response, however this didnt pull the top one from every vendor ID. which is what I need. Then have it order by [Last Invoiced date]. any idea how to accomplish that. Thanks soooo much for your response!

Comment: @Jenesis . . . This question says:  "I was wondering how to just pull the top 1 with the highest "docdate- last date received" could anyone point me in the right direction."  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a question and not in a comment.